# How to fetch keys and values from localStorage html5

Tags: javascript, html

I have added some key values pairs in local storage. Now I want to fetch both values and keys and append its values in li. I am trying to it like this right now.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; ++i ) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(localStorage.getItem(localStorage[key]) + "    " + localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))));
    ol.appendChild(li);
}
```

I want an output key value pairs like:

key1    value1

key2    value2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over object indexes.

```
for (var key in localStorage) {
    var li = document.createElement("li"),
        value = localStorage.getItem(key);

    li.innerHTML = key + " " + value;
    ol.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you put in a check for `localStorage`. If they're in incognito mode, it'll be undefined (or null?).